# SQL multiply row by each element in an array

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have some items in mysql table and I want to multiply the calories field from each row by each element in an array e.g for array `1,2,2`, the first row is multiplied by 1, second row is multiplied by 2, third row is multiplied by 2.

Example table:

```
id | name | calories 
---+------+---------
 1   rice     10
 2   bread    20
 3   apple    15
```

So the output would become:

```
id | name | calories 
---+------+---------
 1   rice     10
 2   bread    40
 3   apple    30
```

I then want to get the total sum of the calories. How should I write the SQL statement in node.js? `req.body.amount` is the array of values that I want to multiply each row of calories by.

```
let sum = [req.body.amount, req.body.name];
let sqlquery = "SELECT SUM(? * calories) AS calories FROM food_item WHERE name IN (?)";
```

Comment: Which row would be the first, which the second, etc ?  Ie. how do you want to order them?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille order by id starting from smallest id.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: @ysth version 5.7.31

Comment: too bad; the relatively easy way to do it within sql requires at least 8.0.19

Comment: @ysth is there a way to convert the array into a column using my version of mysql?

Comment: I'm curious to know if this is continuous. If it is, are those id `AUTO_INCREMENT`? And how do you consider **a set**? Or this `[rice, bread, apple]` is the only set? If there are other sets, how do you separate them? Also, what about the following rows after the third row, will all of them be multiplied by 2? or at some point the multiply values will increase/decrease?

Answer (score 0):

Use the table's id as index for the array.

```
SET @row_number = 0; 
Select t.* , t.calories * factors.factor result
from (
 SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num,
    T1.*
    from test T1) t
 join (
  select f.* from (
  Select 1 as id, 1 as factor
  union Select 2, 2
  Union Select 3,2
  ) f ) factors
   on t.num = factors.id
    Order by t.id;
```

see [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vtwsx61r3iXssgETyPrPBS/2)

Using a json array:

```
SET @row_number = -1;
Select t.* ,
json_extract('{"R": [1,2,2]}' ,
             Concat('$.R[',t.num,']') ) jf,
t.calories * 
json_extract('{"R": [1,2,2]}' ,
             Concat('$.R[',t.num,']') ) result
from (
 SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num,
    T1.*
    from test T1) t
order by t.id;
```

[Db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vtwsx61r3iXssgETyPrPBS/5)